# How can I use a query string with a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, query-string

I'm trying to create web services, and they've been working great so far, but I have one problem: if my query string isn't in the exact order I specify it to be in, the code gives me incorrect results.

Before embarking on a large project, I would like to be able to pass in a query string so that order doesn't matter - passing in "?user=foo&pass=bar" should be equivalent to "?pass=bar&user=foo", but I'm just not sure how to get that working as expected.

As it is, I don't get an error from changing the query string parameters around, but rather DBAgent.authenticate() will just accept the parameters in order regardless of parameter names in the query string.

What am I missing?

IDBAgent.cs:

```
public interface IDBAgent
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/authenticate/?username={username}&password={password}", Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string authenticate(string username, string password);
}
```

DBAgent.svc.cs

```
public class DBAgent : IDBAgent
{
    public string authenticate(string username, string password)
    {
        return runSQL("EXEC sp_Authenticate '" + username + "', '" + password + '\'');
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
var output = "";
function callService(url, params)
{
    try {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                output = msg;
            },
            error: function(){console.log("Oops.")}
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log("Something went wrong! (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻");
    }
}

function authenticate(user, pass)
{
    callService("http://localhost/DBAgent.svc/authenticate/?username=foo&password=bar", []).done();    // Returns true
    console.log(output);
    callService("http://localhost/DBAgent.svc/authenticate/?password=bar&username=foo", []).done();    // Returns false
    console.log(output);
    callService("http://localhost/DBAgent.svc/authenticate/?password=foo&username=bar", []).done();    // Returns true
    console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: yikes you are asking for sql injection. GET is never a good idea for authentication either.

Comment: I've been creating a Frankenstein's monster of code, piecing together snippets and learning how they work as I go.  I haven't converted to POST or protected against SQL injection; I figure that comes after I get something barebones working =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this scenario, you should probably consider using 'POST' instead of 'GET'. Also, please be noted that the order of querystring parameters doesn't matter while using UriTemplate. 
?user=foo&pass=bar" is structurally equivalent to "?pass=bar&user=foo",

Comment: When you say "order doesn't matter", I'm a little confused - my js code shows the exact code I'm using, but the authentication is grabbing the parameters in the order they appear (regardless of the label in front of them).  "?user=foo&pass=bar" and "?pass=foo&user=bar" evaluate to the same values.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what happened, but after playing around with it for a while, this works.  Might be PEBKAC, but thanks!